# Rails migrate date to string?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, migration

I have a field in my db table which is a date rather than string, how do I make a migration to convert it to a string?

```
class CreateKases < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :kases do |t|
    t.date :dateclosed
```

Is it even possible?

Thanks,

Danny

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change a column by using change_column.

```
def self.up
    change_column :kases, :dateclosed, :string
end
```

Hope that helps.